React Sticky Navigation (bulma) Not Working
I wanted to create a sticky navigation with some elements from bulma and initially it worked when i tested it with angular. However, I have migrated to react due to some technical reasons and the navigation bar doesnt seem to be sticky anymore, it will scroll like a normal page. I don't have a lot of experience with react and I tried to create pages and components and importing different components such as navigation+herobody+footer.
Here is the html and the css which I used;
<nav className="navbar mx-auto">
      <div className="container">
        <div id="navMenu" className="navbar-menu">
          <div className="navbar-start ml-4">
            <a className="navbar-item" onClick={() => setPage('home')}>
              Home
            </a>
            <a className="navbar-item" onClick={() => setPage('pricing')}>
              Pricing
            </a>
            <div className="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
              <a className="navbar-link is-arrowless">
                Solutions
              </a>
              <div className="navbar-dropdown">
                <a className="navbar-item" onClick={() => setPage('blog1')}>
                  Item1
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="navbar-end mr-3">
            <div className="navbar-item">
              <div className="buttons">
                <a className="button is-white is-rounded">Contact us</a>
                <a className="button is-link is-rounded">Login</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

.navbar {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 90%;
    position:sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0.5rem;
    z-index: 10; /* to make sure it's above other elements when scrolling */
  }


I have already tried to make the nav position:fixed;top:0.5rem however it still doesn't seem to work.
I personally believe it is a problem of how my components are put together in react rather than the css or html.
Any explanation or help is appreciated!

How can it not be the HTML and CSS? That plus some tangential JS is all a navbar is, no?

Solved: I had to add !important behind the position:sticky since bulma would overwrite my css.

If you solved it you should really submit an answer describing your solution for future viewers who have the same issue.

Add !important after the position:sticky due to bulma overwriting the css.
